# Add stippling to surface plot

Tags: matlab, plot, grid, surface

I have a variable `A` the size 100x150 with temperature values that I've plotted using the `surface` command.

Now I'd like to plot another variable `B` (consisting of 1's and NaN's) over `A` such that the 1's are displayed as some sort of stippling (in black), while nothing happens for the NaN's.

The result should look something like this [IPCC figure](https://www.ipcc.ch/publications_and_data/ar4/wg1/en/fig/figure-spm-7-l.png).

I was able to plot the stippling in `B` separately, by using Markers and setting the colormap to white:

```
figure
surface(longitude, latitude, B, 'edgecolor', 'none', 'marker', 'o');
colormap([1 1 1]);
```

but I don't know how to plot both `A` and `B` in one figure.

I've also tried other commands such as `plot3` but I couldn't figure it out so far.

Any help, also just a hint as to which function to use, would be much appreciated!

Comment: use `hold on`. `figure;hold on; plot(A),plot(B)`

Comment: @Adriaan, thanks for your reply; now I have both plots in one figure but the stippling only 'peeks through' around the edges of `A` , instead of being superimposed, even if I plot `B` first. Why could that be?

Answer (score 1):

You're going to want to create two surfaces, one with your image data and the other will be of the other black regions that you would like to display. To do this, you can either alter the `AlphaData` property of the overlay (shown below) or you can set the `CData` to NaN and those values should be see-through in the resulting image. I think that the `AlphaData` approach is more appropriate since you want the grid to be uniform regardless of the topology of the data.

I have included an example of the `AlphaData` approach below

```
load mri
im = double(squeeze(D(:,:,12)));

figure;

surface(im, 'EdgeColor', 'none');

axis image

% Create an overlay image that will display as black
[w,h] = size(im);

nWide = ceil(w / 10);
nHigh = ceil(h / 10);

checker = checkerboard(10, nWide, nHigh);
checker = checker(1:w, 1:h);

% Now plot the overlay
hold on

[xx,yy] = meshgrid(1:w, 1:h);

s = surface(xx, yy, ones(size(xx))*max(im(:)));

set(s, 'EdgeColor', 'none', ...
       'FaceAlpha', 'flat', ...
       'AlphaData', checker, ...
       'FaceColor', 'black');
```

[image]

And here is the view from the side just so you can see how it was done.

[image]

Alternately, rather than using `surface` you could use [`pcolor`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/pcolor.html) for the overlay:

```
s = pcolor(checker);

set(s, 'EdgeColor', 'none', ...
       'FaceAlpha', 'flat', ...
       'AlphaData', checker, ...
       'FaceColor', 'black)

% And set the ZData so it's above your data
set(s, 'ZData', ones(size(checker)) * max(im(:)))
```

The other nice thing about this approach is that it uses RGB for the color of the overlay so it's appearance is independent of the colormap used for the underlying data.

Comment: @Adriaan technically `pcolor` [is a surface](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/pcolor.html). But that being said, he could simply set the zdata to be a constant matrix = `1.1 * max(A(:))`

Comment: Pretty result now! I'd still keep the `pcolor` though (sorry to be a bore), then the OP can select whatever might be best for him

Comment: @Suever Thanks that worked! The problem however is that while this solution allows me to overlay the black 'checker' data over the underlying data; I still can't figure out how to just plot the stippling. I've tried markers but then I have markers on top of the black 'checkers' ... if you'd have any suggestion on how to fix it I'd be grateful! :-)

Comment: @KimH I'm a little confused here. Why are you trying to **plot** the stippling? The checkered surface that I am using should be replaced by a surface where the `AlphaData` is equal to `~isnan(B)` in your data.

Comment: @KimH in case I wasn't clear, in your code you can set `checker = isnan(B)` rather than what I have where I use `checkerboard`. I can update my answer to include this if it helps.